# Como Fazer uma imagem com php

Tags: php, gd

Eu Gostaria de ao inves do fundo preto por uma imagem, tem como?
Gostaria de fazer igual a esse: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
header("Content-type:image/gif");
$img = imagecreate(470,246);
$azul = imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$branco = imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);

imagettftext($img,25,0,10,50,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","NARUTO SHIPPUDEN");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14,75,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","ASSISTA GRATIS NO ANIMEZONE");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14,75,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","ASSISTA GRATIS NO ANIMEZONE");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14 ,100,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","LEGENDADO / DUBLADO");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14 ,100,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","LEGENDADO / DUBLADO");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14 ,100,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","LEGENDADO / DUBLADO");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14 ,100,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","LEGENDADO / DUBLADO");
imagettftext($img,14,0,14 ,100,$branco,"fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf","LEGENDADO / DUBLADO");

imagegif($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: ja experimentou usar um biblioteca tipo widemagic?

Answer (score 1):

Se consegues colocar a imagem à direita, também deverias conseguir colocar a imagem de fundo.

Com o GD, basta usar a função [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php).

É claro que deve ser a primeira função a ser chamada que altera a imagem.

Além disso, acho que é melhor usar posições relativas. Ou seja, coloca os tamanhos da imagem em variáveis e usa esses valores, com somas e subtrações, para desenhar.